# What is the largest known twin-prime of the form $2^a\cdot 3^b\pm 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, twin-primes

$$2^{2176}\cdot 3^{2175}\pm1$$ is an example of a twin-prime pair of the form $$2^a\cdot 3^b\pm 1$$ with positive integers $a,b$. Each prime "only" has $\ 1\ 693\ $ digits, so larger examples probably exist.

> Have such twin-primes be searched upto a high range ? If yes, what is the largest known twin-prime of this form ?

Update : Enzo Creti found the twin-prime $$2^{5211}\cdot 3^{5794}\pm1$$ with $4\ 334$ digits each.

Comment: This doesn't identify any such primes, but it is of relevance in the search: If $2^a3^b\pm 1$ are primes, then $|a-b|\equiv 1 \mod{2}$. If otherwise, the final digit of $2^a3^b$ will be either $4$ or $6$, making one of $2^a3^b\pm 1$ divisible by $5$. The exception to that parity rule is $5$ itself in the twin prime pair $5,7$, where $a=b=1$.

Comment: Btw $2^{3505}\cdot 3^{2892} \pm 1$ is a larger example.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A027856](https://oeis.org/A027856).